# get that spot out

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**At the cleaning service**

**Manager**: Our work has to be spotless, you know.

**Man**: Spotless?

**Manager**: No spots or stains.

**Man**: I don't understand.

**Manager**: Ha, look. If I spill my coffee on this carpet, it leaves a spot or a stain and we have to **get that spot out** so that the carpet will be

**Man**: Spotless.

**Manager**: All right. Now, how would you **get that spot out**?

**Man**: Oh, well, I, I, oh, with a broom?

**Manager**: No, you cannot sweep up a stain with a broom.

---

What does "**get that spot out**" mean?

Comment: The early part of the dialogue tells you what it means. They are a cleaning company - their job is to remove spots and stains from fabrics.

Comment: I am curious what you think it means. The context leads me to only one conclusion.

Comment: @FeliniusRex If that was addressed to me, my second sentence explains it. What else _could_ it mean?

Comment: @KateBunting I meant it for the OP whom I thought got all comments on a question by default (so no need to address specifically). I'm curious what the OP thought it *could* mean, because I agree with you -- I see only one possible answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means **remove that spot.**  The manager asks, "Now, how would you remove that spot?"  The confusion perhaps comes because the manager's question is chopped.  If he were being more explicit, he would ask, "Now, how would you get that spot *out of the carpet*?"